# Invisible TextView's start to be visible when scrolling ListView

Tags: android, listview, textview

I've got huge problem that I don't understand. I have got custom ListView with my own adapter. Each row in ListView has two TextViews - one is a title and the second one is invisible at start. It's going to be visible when there is something new in this item.

In my adapter I set title for every row and set second TextView to be visible when it should be. When I run my app it's fine, but when i scroll down and up the list almost every row is changing invisible TextView to be visible!

I don't know why, but I spaculate that this is something with `convertView`. Can anybody tell me what's going on?

My adapter:

```
public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private Activity activity;
        private ArrayList<String> titles;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        public MyListAdapter (Activity activity, ArrayList<String> titles) {
            this.activity = activity;
            this.titles = titles;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getLayoutInflater();
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return titles.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View vi=convertView;

            if (convertView == null) {
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wpis_list_row, null);
            }

            TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.movie_title);

            title.setText(titles.get(position));
            String name = titles.get(position);

            if (name.equals("Name 1") || name.equals("Name 2") 
                    || name.equals("Name 3")) {
                TextView news = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.new_sounds);
                news.setVisible(0);
            }

            return vi;
        }
    }
```

and my layout for single row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/movie_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/list_margin"
        android:text="@string/entry"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/new_sounds"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="#8C1717"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:text="@string/news"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where do you set your text view to be invisible? in your code

Comment: @Moh.Sukhni for some reason he sets the with to 0dp

Comment: what's totally wrong.

Comment: I pasted wrong code. Im sorry. Now it is going to be correct.

Comment: this is wrong news.setVisible(0); 0 is the value for visible 
use news.setVisible(View.INVISIBLE) instead.
the value of View.INVISIBLE is 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you are setting the visibility of the text view as visible, based on some if condition . Make sure to change the visibility to gone in the else part.I hope this work . Also you are assigning view view= convertview and then doing if( convertview = null) . Assign the view to convert view in the else part of this check.

Answer (score 0):

To make a `View` invisible in its layout, use `android:visibility` attribute set to `gone` or `invisible` depending on what you want to do.

Programmatically, to change `visibility`, call the `View.setVisibility(VISIBILITY_YOU_WANT)` method. There are some constants in `View` class you can use: `View.GONE` , `View.VISIBLE` , `View.INVISIBLE`.

BTW, read [this post](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296) to better understand the `ListView` `recycling`.

Comment: I have it. I pasted wrong code before. It is like you said. And after I scroll down every row has visible TextView.